# my jquery mobile is not working with my php code

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Below is my code(jquery mobile and php) I am trying to insert into the database and also echo the following message (pls fill all field and registration complete) that is if the user complete the field or not the following message show display but non of it is working with my jquery mobile code and it is working with my normal site how can I fix this I will appreciate it if you work on my code thank you

```
<?php
$db= “user”;
$connect = mysql_connect(“localhost“, “alluser”, “six4”)or die(“could not connect”);
Mysql_select_db($db) or die (“could not select database”);

If (isset($_POST['submit'])){
If(empty($_POST['name']) OR empty($_POST['email']) OR empty($_POST['add'])){
$msg = 'pls fill all field';

$name = ($_POST['name']);
$email = ($_POST['email']);
$address = ($_POST['add']);

mysql_query(“INSERT INTO people (Name, Email, Address”) VALUES ('$name, $email, $address')”) or die (mysql_error());
$msg='registration complete ';
}
}
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>User</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <?php echo “$msg”; ?>
      <form name=“form” action=“” method=“post”>
<label for=“name”>Name</label>
<input type=“text” name=“name” />
<label for=“email”>Email</label>
<input type=“text” name=“email” />
<label for=“address”>Address</label>
<input type=“text” name=“add” />

<input type=“submit” name=“submit” value=“Submit” />
</form>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your brace positions after your `if` statements.  You check for empty values, but you don't alter the program flow in a meaningful way if you find them.

Also, replace your curly quotes with real quotes.  And check for SQL injection.  And double-check your MySQL call.  You'll get an error from PHP before you'll ever get `$msg` echoed, based on the way things are written.